# Elements disappearing on IE7 window resize

Tags: internet-explorer-7, element, css-position

I am coding this web page. http://www.nomizine.com/misc/tbs/default.html

It renders well everywhere except for IE7. When I resize the browser window, top navigation, the compass on the left and subscribe block on the right disappears.

Any idea how to fix it? BTW, I have already tried HasLayout tricks like zoom:1, clear:both etc but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```
#header_bg{
            background: url(../images/header_bg.png) no-repeat center top;
            height:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
            position:relative;
            text-align:center;
            width:100%;         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is the fact that the compass is absolute positioned but the container (the td in this case) is not absolute or relative positioned..

since the absolute positioned elements are positioned in relation to the nearest relative or absolute positioned parent, it could be that IE7 messes up when trying to reclculate (due to the resize) where to put this element..

i would suggest you wrap the `#compass` div with a `div` that has `position:relative`

**[EDIT]**

ok the culprit is `#header_bg` rule in the css file..
just remove the position:relative and all will be back to normal :)

```
#header_bg{
   background: url(../images/header_bg.png) no-repeat center top;
   /*position:relative;*/
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Gaby for sparing some time to answer.

First off, I tried removing absolute position from compass and it worked. But what about navigation above it and subscribe box to the right still disappear even they are positioned relative already?

Second, I tried that relative positioned parent trick but no good. Any idea?

Comment: ok i found the culprit ...

look at edit above .. (it was another relative that was causing the trouble..)

Comment: haha! I found the culprit for myself as well. But I didn't remove the position:relative;. What I did that I added some more properties like width, height, margin etc and it worked. Strange behavior. I guess it has something to do with HasLayout peroperty of the browser. I am not going to figure it tho. For now, my problem is solved. Thanks for the effort again Gaby. :)

Comment: glad you got it figured out :)